# How to disable material preview icons?

Tags: materials

Very often when i have a lot of materials in the scene and switching to materials tab, blender starts to rendering that materials to make a preview icons. This procedure taking a lot of memory and is cause of crashes when you have many materials(specially complex materials) and low RAM.

Comment: are you talking of the "preview" panel in the "material" data tab in "properties" editor? if so, did you try to collapse the "preview" panel, so that the image is not visible? (not sure that helps...)

Comment: no, i am talking about that small icons that you see on the left side of material name.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for awhile, especially when working with complex material setups. I think I have found a work-around.

Try switching the *Properties* panel (on the left) to another tab. ie. Anything except the *Material Properties* tab. This should stop the preview of the material from being re-rendered in the background.